# Как правильно сделать вычисления на VueJs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Как правильно производить вычисления на **VueJs** ?
Сейчас необходимо сделать калькулятор заработка водителя при определенных условиях, таких как:

- "День недели"
- "Время"
- "Автомобиль(свой или аренда)"
- "Сумма заработка в час(зависит от дня недели и времени)"

Если выбрать понедельник, то необходимо в выпадающем списке сделать время, с которого по которое будет человек работать, так как в разные временные промежутки сумма разная (но с понедельника по четверг они одинаковые каждый день).
**`Понедельник : 02:00 - 07:00 | 350|400 |`** 
Далее с 7 часов идет другая сумма, и так до 24 часов.
В макет страницы уже вывел все данные из Vue

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#calc',
    data: {
      autos: [
        {item: 'Свой автомобиль'},
        {item: 'Арендованный автомобиль'},
      ],
      hrs: [
          {item: '01:00',summ1: 350, summ2: 400},
          {item: '02:00',summ1: 350, summ2: 400},
          {item: '03:00',summ1: 250, summ2: 330},
          {item: '04:00',summ1: 250, summ2: 330},
          {item: '05:00',summ1: 250, summ2: 330},
          {item: '06:00',summ1: 250, summ2: 330},
          {item: '07:00',summ1: 450, summ2: 450},
          {item: '08:00',summ1: 450, summ2: 450},
          {item: '09:00',summ1: 380, summ2: 450},
          {item: '10:00',summ1: 380, summ2: 450},
          {item: '11:00',summ1: 260, summ2: 350},
          {item: '12:00',summ1: 260, summ2: 350},
          {item: '13:00',summ1: 260, summ2: 350},
          {item: '14:00',summ1: 260, summ2: 350},
          {item: '15:00',summ1: 260, summ2: 350},
          {item: '16:00',summ1: 290, summ2: 370},
          {item: '17:00',summ1: 330, summ2: 330},
          {item: '18:00',summ1: 330, summ2: 360},
          {item: '19:00',summ1: 280, summ2: 380},
          {item: '20:00',summ1: 320, summ2: 380},
          {item: '21:00',summ1: 320, summ2: 380},
          {item: '22:00',summ1: 370, summ2: 420},
          {item: '23:00',summ1: 370, summ2: 420},
          {item: '24:00',summ1: 370, summ2: 420},
      ],
      days : [
          {item:'Понедельник'},
          {item:'Вторник'},
          {item:'Среда'},
          {item:'Четверг'},
          {item:'Пятница'},
          {item:'Суббота'},
          {item:'Воскресение'}
      ],
    }
})
```

суммы указанные в списке hrs - это суммы с понедельника по четверг. а так же должны быть еще и в пятницу и в субботу и в воскресение! Суммы везде разные.

Искал калькуляторы подобные. Нашел на подобном же сайте [Пример калькулятора](https://rabota-yandex-taksi.ru/raschet-zarabotka) .

Как реализовать подобный калькулятор?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо сделать форму, куда пользователь будет вводить данные, и поля, куда будут записываться введённые данные.
Результаты можно посчитать внутри вычисляемых свойств, что удобно, тк не нужно заботиться о пересчёте результата при обновлении зависимостей, а также не требуется создавать переменную под хранение результата. И отобразить просто.

Ну а дальше всё сами!